# Angular Routing in Development Mode doesn't rewrite URLs properly

Tags: angular, routes

Using Angular 8.2.0

I'm having an issue normally seen when deploying an Angular app to a web server where the server must be configured to rewrite URLs to serve index.html in order for Angular routing to work. I'm this issue while running in development mode with `ng serve`.

I'm unable to create routes longer than one segment. 
Example app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ConstructorLandingComponent } from './constructor-landing/constructor-landing.component';
import { EventDetailsViewComponent } from './event-details-view/event-details-view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'landing',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'nest/test',
    component: ConstructorLandingComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'landing',
    component: ConstructorLandingComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'details',
    component: EventDetailsViewComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Any route with a single level (e.g. `localhost:4200/landing`) works fine, but if I try to access `localhost:4200/nest/test`, the angular dev server looks for the angular runtime at `localhost:4200/nest/runtime.js`, for example. My understanding is the Angular CLI is supposed to handle URL rewriting for you. Is it possible there's an issue with my angular.json? Or maybe I'm missing something really obvious.

Edit: 
Here's the architect section of angular.json including the `build` and `serve` sections:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/navigator",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
                "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
        },
        "configurations": {
            "production": {
                "fileReplacements": [{
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }],
                "optimization": true,
                "outputHashing": "all",
                "sourceMap": false,
                "extractCss": true,
                "namedChunks": false,
                "aot": true,
                "extractLicenses": true,
                "vendorChunk": false,
                "buildOptimizer": true,
                "budgets": [{
                        "type": "initial",
                        "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                        "maximumError": "5mb"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                        "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                        "maximumError": "10kb"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "staging": {
                "fileReplacements": [{
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }],
                "optimization": true,
                "outputHashing": "all",
                "sourceMap": false,
                "extractCss": true,
                "namedChunks": false,
                "aot": true,
                "extractLicenses": true,
                "vendorChunk": false,
                "buildOptimizer": true,
                "budgets": [{
                        "type": "initial",
                        "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                        "maximumError": "5mb"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                        "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                        "maximumError": "10kb"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
        "options": {
            "browserTarget": "navigator:build"
        },
        "configurations": {
            "production": {
                "browserTarget": "navigator:build:production"
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your configuration of architect.serve from inside your angular.json?

Comment: Can you also share your code form ConstructorLandingComponent?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

should be in your index.html

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.